# Converting set of points to ellipses with support for overlay_nearest grouping and field filters using QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, geometry-generator, qgis-expression, ellipse

I am trying to build an expression that transforms in real-time using the Geometry generator the geometry from points to ellipses.

The expression I am working with is the following:

```
oriented_bbox(
    collect($geometry,
        group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer,"CLUSTER_ID"))
    )
```

As you can see, from a set of points I create the oriented_bbox object grouped by the nearest and filter by a field. The goal is to add the function `make_ellipse` so that, in real-time, it converts the oriented_bbox objects to ellipses:

[image]

I have tried to adapt the following expression that has appeared as a solution posted by the user @MrXsquared to this question [Making ellipse based on ellipse-like polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395533/making-ellipse-based-on-ellipse-like-polygon-in-qgis):

```
make_ellipse(
    centroid($geometry),
    bounds_width($geometry)/2,
    bounds_height($geometry)/2,
    main_angle($geometry),
    45
    )
```

My attempt was as follows but it didn't work. I'm also not sure that the `make_ellipse` function can work with the idea of grouping objects by nearest and applying filters.

```
make_ellipse(
    oriented_bbox(
        collect($geometry,
            group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer,"CLUSTER_ID")),
        ),
    centroid($geometry),
    bounds_width($geometry)/2,
    bounds_height($geometry)/2,
    main_angle($geometry),
    45)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. But instead of [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#geometry), which in your case is a point, you need to reference the bounding box you have created with your first expression. The easiest and shortest way to do this is to use a variable.

```
with_variable(
    'bbox',
    oriented_bbox(
        collect($geometry,
        group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer, "CLUSTER_ID")
        )
    ),

make_ellipse(
    centroid(@bbox),
    bounds_width(@bbox)/2,
    bounds_height(@bbox)/2,
    main_angle(@bbox),
    45
    )
)
```

Respectively, if you want to use the other expression from my linked answer:

```
with_variable(
    'bbox',
    oriented_bbox(
        collect($geometry,
        group_by:=overlay_nearest(@layer, "CLUSTER_ID")
        )
    ),

make_ellipse(
    centroid(@bbox),
    bounds_width(@bbox)/2,
    bounds_height(@bbox)/2,
    main_angle(
        make_line(
            centroid(@bbox),
            closest_point(centroid(@bbox),@bbox)
            )
        )-90,
    45
    )
)
```

And a hint in case this slows down your rendering: this is because your layer is based on points. So even if you ***see*** only 6 bounding boxes / ellipses, you ***actually have*** as many bounding boxes / ellipses as you have points. This is because the expression is applied to every feature (point) in your layer.

Comment: More than a solution. A way to learn how to integrate expressions. Thank's!

Comment: Regarding the last remark about rendering, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/426593/128665) for how to prevent duplicating geometries.